# SMTP server in Python using sockets is apparently inaccessible through Gmail

Tags: python, sockets, email, smtp

I decided to play around with the SMTP and wrote a very simple test script in Python:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("",25))
sock.listen(1)

print("Server started...")
while True:
    conn,addr = sock.accept()
    print(addr,"connected")
    print(conn.recv(4096))
    conn.close()
```

The script does exactly what I want it to do when I connect to it via ncat: it prints out the data it gets, then closes.  I also set up my router to forward connections on port 25 to my computer, so it should be able to be accessed externally.

However, when I send an email via Gmail to test@<my ip address>, I never receive it.  Why does this happen?

I understand that there is a SMTP library for Python, but I'm not trying to make a serious mail server, I just want to learn how it works.

As I have said before, I don't understand SMTP very well, but I was under the assumption that it would work pretty much like any other network protocol and I would be able to at least print out the request I would get using this program.

Comment: I'm not certain, but you may need to have some domain name with [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) established in order for external mail servers such as Gmail to attempt to deliver mail there. Just addressing an email to `test@<my ip address>` wouldn't be enough.

Comment: potato, your post lacks a question. Do you have a specific question that you'd like answered?

Comment: @JoshKupershmidt After some research, this looks like it may be correct.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 2):

The text, `test@<my ip address>` isn't a valid syntax for an email address.

Assuming that your ip address is, say, 198.51.100.43, try this email address:

```
test@[198.51.100.43]
```

References:

- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt , section 4.1.3

Comment: Unfortunately, gmail doesn't accept addresses formatted like that.  However, I'm having trouble imagining that being too much of a problem in actually communicating to the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

> As I have said before, I don't understand SMTP very well, but I was under the assumption that it would work pretty much like any other network protocol and I would be able to at least print out the request I would get using this program.

I suggest that your understanding of *"pretty much like any other network protocol"* is too much influenced by HTTP. Because all the classic protocols like SMTP, FTP, IMAP, POP, NNTP ... consist of several handshakes between client and server and the first one for all of these protocols is a message from the server. Which means that the SMTP client will connect to the server and time out after a while because the initial greeting was not received.

For the basic specification of SMTP see [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), but there will be others to read if you want to support TLS and other extensions.

Comment: Yes, but such a connection (and any request accompanying it) should have been logged with my program even if it timed out later.

Comment: I guess there are simply multiple problems. First the MTA will not even try to deliver the mail to your server because you've specified the target wrong and once you've solved this the delivery will fail because you don't do proper SMTP.